# Cocoa - How to bind width of a NSView in InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, binding

I'm trying to create a simple application that draws a grid in a custom view.
The custom view size is fixed (it doesn't depend on the size of the window).

The custom view is embedded in a scroll view to be able to explore the grid when the scroll view can't display the entire custom view.

Now i want to add sliders for controlling the grid parameters (nb raws, nb columns, tile width, tile height, ...), and these parameters influence the size of the custom view.

As an experiment, i'm trying to bind one slider's value to the width of my custom view but fail to find a way to do it.

How am i supposed to do this sort of things ?
Is it possible to do it in InterfaceBuilder ? I expected to find a width binding in Bindings Inspector Window but it's not there, curiously ;-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind the width of a plain NSView, and binding to a property of a view is always a bad idea. View properties are seldom observable. Moreover, there is no `width` property; it's one member of the structure that is the value of the `frame` property, which you must set all at once or not at all.

As for exposing bindings in your custom view, you can do that, provided you keep the properties [observable](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/) (which consists of little more than only changing the property's value using its setter). You'll need to expose the bindings in your view class's `initialize` method, and you'll need to [write an IBPlugin](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/).

See also the [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/).

Comment: Ouch! That's more work than i expected...
I added an action in the custom view to call setFrameWidth and bound the action to the slider. It mostly works but doesn't cope well with the job done by the scroll view. When the custom view is small enough to be displayed entirely it is placed in the lower left corner of the scroll view instead of being centered.


Thanks